# how to overlay the action bar and hide title bar also

Tags: java, android

I want to overlay the action bar and also hide the title bar.I have tried this

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY );
```

But both is not working ,only one of the feature is working at a time.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the actionbar into a variable first... you can then use that variable to do anything you want e.g

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

For androidbar overlay create a custom android bar theme. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Comment: try using the manifest file to remove the screen title (action bar will still remain) then you can use the link i posted above to do the overlay. That should do it... Goodluck

Manifest example: Set label as ""
<activity
            android:name=".MyAndroidScreen"
........     
            android:label="">
        </activity>